# Question about Circuit-SAT NP-Complete Proof

Tags: complexity-theory

I have two questions about the proof that Circuit-SAT is NP-Complete from here (just the first 1.5 pages):
https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/teaching/cs170-s03/Notes/lecture22.pdf

1. The THEOREM 1 states that the size of $C_n$ is bounded by some polynomial in $n$. Where is this necessary in the proof? It seems like what really matters (coming from the reduction definition) is that we can find $C_n$ in polynomial time. I am not sure where the size comes in.
2. How would one "hard-wire" $G$ into the circuit in the second paragraph? I understand why it is necessary. However, wouldn't one need to also show that this hard-wiring takes polynomial time as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're right.  All that matters is that the reduction runs in polynomial time.  (It follows that the circuit has polynomial size, since the output of any polynomial-time algorithm must be polynomial in length.)
2. Given a circuit with multiple inputs, you can force some of the inputs to 0 or 1.  If the circuit has polynomial size, this modification takes polynomial time, since you're only modifying at most polynomially much stuff.